# Warning: org.json.me.JSONArray: can't find referenced class java.lang.StringBuilder

Tags: java, java-me

> Warning: org.json.me.JSONArray: can't
>   find referenced class
>   java.lang.StringBuilder

I have checked all java file of json.me but in that no `java.lang.StringBuilder` is used

I got this warning when I am compiling my j2me project.

How to remove this warning from project. I got this json.me from this link
[Download link of json.me](https://github.com/upictec/org.json.me)

Please  give me solution about that.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.StringBuilder` is found in the JDK. I think `StringBuffer` is available in Java ME. Use that instead.

Also, I checked the code from the link provided, I see no reference to `StringBuilder` but I see references to `StringBuffer`.

Comment: ya but in JSONArray there is not used StringBuilder

Comment: that means StringBuilder not used in json.me but it showing warning of can't find referenced class java.lang.StringBuilder

Comment: Can you find out where the warning is referenced to?

Comment: ya in build-impl.xml:432                                              <nb-obfuscate srcjar="${obfuscator.srcjar}" destjar="${obfuscator.destjar}" obfuscatorclasspath="${obfuscator.classpath}" classpath="${platform.bootclasspath}:${extra.classpath}" obfuscationLevel="${obfuscation.level}" extraScript="${obfuscation.custom}"/>

Comment: & it Showing like that   Error: Please correct the above warnings first.
D:\Sajid\J2Meproject1\nbproject\build-impl.xml:432: Obfuscation failed with error code 1.

Comment: Make sure your classpath doesn't point to any library used by the JDK. Find out where `${platform.bootclasspath}:${extra.classpath}` points to.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error learning j2me right now.  Fixed it by adding a compiler flag: 'javac -source 1.4 ....' .

The reason is, Java 1.5+ uses StringBuilder which replaces StringBuffer.  But JavaME implementation doesn't have the  StringBuilder, it requires using the old StringBuffer for the same operations. So compile your J2ME class as Java 1.4 so it uses the old method.

Comment: Hey Hi, I solved this error.. when you download the JSON.ME after that u need to compile all this classes of JSON.ME using jdk1.6.0 (that means higher version) then my problem was solved.