# json.me got error in J2ME Project

Tags: java, java-me, j2mepolish

Hey Hi Friends,
I am working on J2ME project & I have used Json.me in project but when I have imported the org.json.me.* in my class file & try to compile it, it shows warnings & Build failed.
What happening with this I don't know.
This is Warnings & Build Failed....

```
Warning: org.json.me.JSONTokener: can't find referenced class java.lang.StringBuilder
Warning: org.json.me.JSONTokener: can't find referenced class java.lang.StringBuilder
Warning: org.json.me.JSONTokener: can't find referenced class java.lang.StringBuilder
Warning: org.json.me.JSONTokener: can't find referenced class java.lang.StringBuilder
Warning: org.json.me.JSONTokener: can't find referenced class java.lang.StringBuilder
Warning: org.json.me.JSONTokener: can't find referenced class java.lang.StringBuilder
Warning: org.json.me.JSONArray: can't find referenced class java.lang.StringBuilder
Warning: org.json.me.JSONArray: can't find referenced class java.lang.StringBuilder
Warning: org.json.me.JSONArray: can't find referenced class java.lang.StringBuilder
Warning: org.json.me.JSONArray: can't find referenced class java.lang.StringBuilder
Warning: org.json.me.JSONArray: can't find referenced class java.lang.StringBuilder
Warning: org.json.me.JSONArray: can't find referenced class java.lang.StringBuilder
Warning: org.json.me.JSONObject: can't find referenced class java.lang.StringBuilder
Warning: org.json.me.JSONObject: can't find referenced class java.lang.StringBuilder
Warning: org.json.me.JSONObject: can't find referenced class java.lang.StringBuilder
Warning: org.json.me.JSONObject: can't find referenced class java.lang.StringBuilder
Warning: org.json.me.JSONObject: can't find referenced class java.lang.StringBuilder
Warning: there were 17 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars'),
         or perhaps the '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses' option.
Error: Please correct the above warnings first.
D:\Sajid\\Workspace_netbean\JGame\nbproject\build-impl.xml:432: Obfuscation failed with error code 1.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Can any one help me please....
Thanks

Comment: Didn't you ask this [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259174/warning-org-json-me-jsonarray-cant-find-referenced-class-java-lang-stringbuild)   ?

Comment: ya i have asked before but didn't get answers......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have an old version of Java, like 1.4.2 or so. StringBuilder was introduced in in version 1.5.

Comment: @Sajid, java-me **doesn't** support 1.6